# Simplifying the determinant of a $3×3$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Suppose we have the following matrix:
$$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
x+\dfrac12&8&-\dfrac{27}2\\ 
-\dfrac12&x+10& -\dfrac{27}{2}\\ 
-\dfrac12&8&x-\dfrac{21}2 
\end{bmatrix}$$

My goal is to find the determinant of matrix A. One can see the matrix A as:
$$ xI-B=A $$
So finding the determinant of A is the same as finding the characterist polynomial of B.
 I know the result is:
$$det(A)=x^3 $$

Which can be determined. However, the calculation of such determinant takes a long time.

My question is if there is any way to simplify the calculation and save some time.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Using row operations, you should try to introduce some zeroes. For example, replacing the second row by the difference of the second with third row gives a zero at the left of the second row. Recall that this does not change the determinant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the second row of $A$ to the first one and if you subtract the second line from the third one, the determinant stays the same and the matrix becomes$$\begin{pmatrix}x&x+18&-27\\-\frac12&x+10&-\frac{27}2\\0&-x-2&x+3\end{pmatrix}.$$Now, if you add to the first line the second one times $2x$, again the determinant stays the same and you get$$\begin{pmatrix}0&2x^2+21x+18&-27x-27\\-\frac12&x+10&-\frac{27}2\\0&-x-2&x+3\end{pmatrix}.$$Now, thanks to thos two $0$'s, it's quite easy to see that the determinant is $x^3$.

---

You can also check that $B^3$  is the null matrix. Therefore, its characteristic polynomial is $x^3$.